# VB 2010 Login system

Tags: vb.net-2010

I've been trying to make a login system some time but couldn't find a good tutorial or code. But then i found this code that worked as it should. Except there's a little problem. The problem is that i get a syntax error and i haven't been able to find a solution too this error.

Can you please help?

When i write this: Do passline = TextBox2.Text userline = USERREAD.ReadLine
It says that passline is a syntax error.

This is the code:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("You need atleast 1 Character", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
ElseIf My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Rebecca\Desktop\ACCOUNTS\ACCOUNTS" + TextBox1.Text + "\") Then
    Dim USERREAD As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Rebecca\Desktop\ACCOUNTS\ACCOUNTS" + TextBox1.Text + "\" + "username.txt")
    Dim userline As String
    Dim PASSREAD As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Rebecca\Desktop\ACCOUNTS\ACCOUNTS" + TextBox2.Text + "\" + "password.txt")
    Dim passline As String
    Do passline = TextBox2.Text userline = USERREAD.ReadLine Console.WriteLine(passline)
    Console.WriteLine(userline)
    Loop Until userline Is Nothing
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a Password(", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ERROR")
    ElseIf passline = PASSREAD.ReadLine() = True Then
        MsgBox("Welcome to LoginSystem " + TextBox1.Text)
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    Else : MsgBox("The information you entered is Incorrect", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ERROR")
End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is caused by missing new lines in your `Do` loop, change to this:

```
    Do
        passline = TextBox2.Text
        userline = USERREAD.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine(passline)
        Console.WriteLine(userline)
    Loop Until userline Is Nothing
```